# Delay between slides with simple jQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fade

I'm trying to set up a slideshow that fades from one image to the next, with about a 3 second pause on each slide. I can't get it to pause on each element, though the delay works to pause the first image.

**Is there a way to add an element to the code below so that each image can be viewed for longer before the fade effect begins?**

It's my first time working with jQuery, so the simpler the better. thanks!

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="images/baby-slide.png"/>
    <img src="images/characters-slide.png"/>  
    <img src="images/engagement-slide.png" />
    <img src="images/holidays-slide.png"/>
    <img src="images/sports-slide.png"/> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed:  2000, 
            delay: 2000,
            continuous:1, 
            timeout:0, 
            easeIn: 'linear', 
            easeOut: 'linear', 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `continuous:0` and `timeout:3000`.

From [the documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html):

> continuous: true to start next transition immediately after current
> one completes
>
> timeout: milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto
> advance)

Comment: When I put that in, then nothing at all happens and the slideshow doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to set the timeout also. Your current value of zero disables auto advance.

Comment: Thanks for sending that documentation, though- now I see that what I had to do was set the timeout to something other than 0.

Comment: Aaah- now I understand. i had thought that I had tried to change the timeout before posting this question, but it hadn't work. That's because I had to change continuous as well. Amazing, thanks a lot.